# Javascript library wanted for XML editor programatically generated from XSD

Tags: javascript, xml, xforms

I want to create a web based interface to configure a system. My systems configuration is defined using XML for which I have an XML schema. I am looking for a Java Library which takes this schema and automatically creates a nice web based interface for viewing and editing the XML configuration document.

It would be nice if this library would allow compound elements to be expanded and hidden and of course ensured the resultant XML is compliant with the XSD.

Should I be using Xform somewhere in here?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Xopus](http://xopus.com). It is a browser based XML editor written in Javascript. It takes an XML Document, an XML Schema and an XSLT as input.

Xopus is targeted at non technical users and will disable/hide all UI options that would make the documention invalid according to the specified XML Schema.

The XSLT is used to create a WYSIWYG editing view. Expanding and hiding of parts of the document can be easily added by dynamically setting XSLT parameters using the [Xopus DOM API](http://xopus.com/documentation/developer-guide/reference/xopus-api.html).

Comment: Xopus doesn't support Chrome or Safari.